# How to export store's csv that Excel will read properly?

Tags: csv, export, character-encoding

In Sales > Orders when I export csv and open it in excel some characters are not encoded properly. e.g: ü is exported as:  Ã¼ etc.

Do suggest some solution to this problem. Thanks

Comment: Preferred This Link It May Help You!!!

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42929/order-export-to-csv-%C3%82%C2%A3-instead-of-%C2%A3

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki  I have tried it , but problem still persists, recommend some other solution please.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend from this and share my experience.

I use https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html for grid customization and it also has a cool export feature built in.

As well as that I also use an extension called https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-jalappeno-order-export.html which is HIGHLY customizable in the extensions model - if you'd like to give a little bit more information on what you want the export to look like I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, when exported csv file is opened in other editors i.e other than Ms excel, there is no encoding problem but when I open it in MS excel, many characters have encoding problem.

Comment: Suggest some solution other than using any extension.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26871596/2680550

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215700/change-charset-for-csv-export-file/26871596#26871596, I have used this one but it do not works.

Comment: ,recommend some other solution please.